# GWT SimplePager - not displaying buttons

Tags: gwt, datagrid, simplepager

I have a DataGrid that I want to add pagination to.  Following the example from the docs, I have:

```
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(resultsGrid);

    // Create a Pager to control the table.
    SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
    pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources,true, 50, true);
    pager.setDisplay(resultsGrid);
```

However, I get neither the 'forward' nor 'fast forward' buttons:
[image]

Is there something I"m missing?  Do I need to do something when the DataProvider changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your previous question and screenshot, the remaining pager buttons on the right are simply hidden under the west pane.

Comment: Yes, that is the case.  By solving that problem, the buttons appeared.